# Change groupField and reload grid Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, grid

How i can change groupField and reload grid. Please help me. Thanks

## List.ascx

```
<td style="width: 20px"><input type="radio" name="grouping" value="AgencyName"/></td>
        <td style="width: 50px"> AgencyName</td>
         <td style="width: 20px"><input type="radio" name="grouping" value="HotelName" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td style="width: 50px"> HotelName</td>
```

## EntryStore.js

```
Ext.define('HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.EntryStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
start: '',

requires: [
    'HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.EntryModel',
    'Ext.ux.grid.feature.*'
],

constructor: function (cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'EntryStore',
        model: 'HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.EntryModel',
        groupField: "AgencyName",
        pageSize: 100,
        proxy: {
            url: 'Modules/Reports/EntryListGridHandler.ashx',
            extraParams: {
                f: '',
                id: '',
                seq: 0,
                cols: '["CustomerTitle","CustomerName","CustomerNationality","CustomerPassport","CustomerBirthDate","CustomerAge","CustomerArrival","CustomerArrivalTime","CustomerDeparture","CustomerDepartureTime","ConfirmationStatusString","ReservationTypeString","ReservationStatusString","HotelName","AgencyName","VoucherNo","SellDate","CheckIn","CheckOut","Nights","RoomName","RoomTypeName","AccomName","RoomCount","SoldPrice","SoldCurrency","ExtraServicesInfo","Adults","Childs","Infants","Pax"]',
                filters: '',
                excl: '',
                renew: true,
                statusfilter: '',
                refreshGridFilter: false,

}
```

## EntryListGrid.js

```
Ext.create('HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.EntryStore');
grid = Ext.create('HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.EntryGrid');
operGrid = Ext.create('HotelWeb.HotelSite.js.OperationGrid', { hidden: true });

resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    xtype: 'panel',
    renderTo: 'entryListGrid',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        pack: 'start'
    },
    items: [
        grid,
        {
            xtype: 'splitter',
            id: 'splitter',
            hidden: true
        },
        operGrid
    ]
});
```

How I can set groupField from radio input. I will radio button changed
 `grid.store.groupField = value` but I must recreate grid

Answer (score 0):

Grid panel has [reconfigure](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) function, which allows to use another store and column's set for the same grid component. Or, if you want group the data in the store immediately, you can use ***group*** method of the store component.